# Drag and Drop with sectioned background

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-drop, sharepoint

Imagine a whiteboard which has a number of sections (a table):
[image: drag-drop-table]

Then you have a number of cards/titles/images/whatever which you would like to drag and drop onto.

Basically, my area at work do strategy and finance, and we need to often move items (prospective projects) around various 'Strategy' boxes, considering available budget over the next 4 years. We need to move things in out out of the holding area (Triage), to the various boxes, as we try and figure out which are the most important projects to fund.

That's what I need, preferably JS/HTML 5, and hosted locally on a server, not the internet (sensitive info). If it could be embedded using jQuery/CSS in SharePoint 2013 (stop laughing), that would be even better.

We are doing this in PowerPoint at the moment. There must be a better way, which we can then screengrab for documents (or print). Think KanBan but able to move between various boxes in rows, not just columns. Snapping to various boxes e.g: 
https://bevacqua.github.io/dragula/ (except many more boxes in rows and columns).

Thanks for any suggestions on applications or code to get this done.

Comment: This may be a better basic example (nested grid): 
https://supraniti.github.io/Lean-Mean-Drag-and-Drop/

Comment: I implemented this on a website. Then realized that mobile users do not like such things. By the way, do you need mobile support?

Comment: No need for mobile support. We'd use in in-house and just take screengrabs to put into powerpoint etc.

Comment: The Dragula you mention looks great. What is its problem exactly? You can not put more than given number of boxes into each "cell"?

Comment: The Nested Grid looks a lot better and closer to what I need. I just don't have the coding skills.

Comment: Definitely think https://supraniti.github.io/Lean-Mean-Drag-and-Drop/ would be the better solution I have found so far, if anyone could assist.

Comment: I've messed around with the lean-mean-drag-and-drop to get the layout I want, but how do you get the changes to be stored, so that if the browser is shut, when the page is next opened, it remembers where the 'cards' were last located?